# Disk space doesn't release after delete table.

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

I deleted a table with about 300Gb size, but reserved disk space dose not release also after shrink file and shrink database and  `DBCC UPDATEUSAGE (0)` command.

Comment: SQL Server keeps once allocated disk space for future use

Comment: Which recovery mode does your database use? If 'full recovery', then you have to make full backup to reclaim log file space. If 'simple', then shrink your db again, with moving data pages to file beginning.

Comment: @Arvo it's 'simple' mode and i shrieked db and file, but disk space did not release.

Comment: In SSMS 2012 while shrinking db or file there is option like 'Reorganize pages before releasing unused space' - did you check it?

Comment: What works is a truncate. Not handy but you can copy data truncate table put data back. But I'm still looking for simpler and safer solution